# Cannot check-in recent code changes to Visual Studio Online

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

For some reason I cannot check in my code to our Visual Studio Online account. Other developers can, but not me. This is the error I am getting:

"Could not find dataspace with category VersionControl and identifier *[some guid]*"

Searching for any help on the above error is not returning anything meaningful.

This started to happen after I installed Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I launched it for the first time after creating a new web application with Visual Studio 2013. I then opened that new solution in 2015 and all was fine. Things began to go awry once I tried to put it in our Visual Studio Online account. When I went to Team Explorer in VS 2015 I selected "Projects and My Teams / New Team Project". This then bounced me over to our Visual Studio Online account in the browser for me to fill out that simple form to create a new team project. I filled the form out and submitted. I then got an error that the project was **not** successfully created. Unfortunately Visual Studio still thinks it was created and it shows up in the list of projects ONLY WITHIN Visual Studio -- it does not show up online. Eventually I just became frustrated and deleted everything related to all that I just tried but then learned that I cannot check anything in now on my old projects! I had other developers test and they still can so the problem evidently is on my machine. I then uninstalled VS 2013 and VS 2015 then reinstalled VS 2013 and am still having the problem.

I am hoping someone can point me to some cached junk that needs to be cleared on my system. :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit shot in the dark, few things you can try:

1. Delete the local cache under:

   `%localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation`
   `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\SyncSettings`
2. Open cmd. Type:

   - `"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools\vsvars32.bat"`
   - Verify connections: `tf settings connections`
   - Run Visual Studio in safe mode (`devenv.exe /SafeMode`)
   - Run Visual Studio with activity log ([`devenv.exe /log`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241272.aspx)) and check for errors.