# Visual Studio Version Control Error that prevents being able to perform code reviews etc

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

I have had this error several times and all resources I have found related to it are old enough that VS has changed file locations/how things operate that they are not able to be used anymore.

I'm using Windows 10, and this is VS 2017 Enterprise edition.
[Visual Studio Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNWwy.png)

Previously I have been able to fix this error by uninstalling VS, restarting my computer, and reinstalling again. Usually works for a few weeks or so, but once I get it, I haven't been able to find another way around it.

I have tried these "fixes" already: [Previous Stack question - old version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31711141/7906434)

None of these solutions have worked, and ultimately would like to find something that doesn't result in the reinstall of VS.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Vsts ? or TFS? If TFS then what version of it?

Comment: Does your issue happen when you connect to TFS only? Do you see this error if your don't connect to TFS?

Comment: @Jared Hanson, It seems that the same issue has been reported here:   https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/308114/could-not-find-dataspace-with-category-versioncont.html, but if possible, you could share us much more information about this issue, so we could really troubleshooting this issue.